# Set base paths for my files for webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

When using `requirejs`, I do this:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "scripts"
});
console.log("Starting!");
require(["A", "B", "C"], mainFunction);
```

I was googling how to set the base path for Webpack. I found [`resolve.root`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root). However that just doesn't work:

```
$ node run_with_node.js
D:\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:19
                throw new WebpackOptionsValidationError(webpackOptionsValidationErrors);
                ^

WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
    at webpack (D:\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:19:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\web\voxnap\run_with_node.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
```

I also tried to use `resolve.modules`, but if I did that, Webpack couldn't find internal modules from babeljs.

```
Error: Cannot find module "babel-runtime/helpers/typeof"
```

So how to properly add a directory that contains my scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've looked at the documentation for webpack 1. Webpack 2 removed `resolve.root` and unified it to [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules), as shown in the [Migration Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) of the official webpack 2+ docs.

The default value of `resolve.modules` is `["node_modules"]` and if you want to keep the regular module resolution, you have to include it as well.

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "scripts"),
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow up question though: Webpack seems to be loading 0.js instead of my libraries. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45400982/607407

Comment: @Michael can you provide this solution for webpack 5?