# Error: Loading chunk 0 failed. - webpack tries to load 0.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have following project structure:

```
|-mainFile.js
|-scripts -
          |-Library1.js
          |-Library2.js
```

Library files use requirejs `define([], function() {})` syntax.

I've therefore put this into the webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'scripts'),
            // The normal path
            "node_modules"
        ]
    },
    /** ... **/
}
```

I then do this in `mainFile.js` which is entry point for webpack:

```
require(["Library1", "Library2"], function(Library1, Library2) { ... });
```

And I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/0.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]
Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
Stack trace:
onScriptComplete@http://localhost:3000/player/webpack_build.js:100:24
                     webpack_build.js:146:52
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/0.js” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More]
test_file.html Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
```

So webpack tries to load some `0.js` file. What's that supposed to be?

Answer (score 4):

I have figured out a fix, I hope it helps.

For my React Routes, I'm using dynamic loading with import statements, without the CommonChunks plugin.

I was getting the same error (or "Chunk 1", "Chunk 2", etc) depending on the route I was loading. I finally realized that my asset bundles were actually being outputted into the current directory that my html was in, even though my output.path was pointing to the assets folder.

To fix this, I just set my output.chunkFilename to '../../../assets/js/com/[name].bundle.js', which then output it to the correct folder.

From then on, my app was able to find my bundles and it worked great!

Hope it helps,
Michael

Answer (score 3):

The [AMD `require`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-amd-version-) loads the modules asynchronously and works like [`require.ensure`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-ensure). Webpack will split out these dynamic imports and request them when they are used. If you don't give them a name they will be numbered (`0.js` etc. or what you configured in [`output.chunkFilename`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-chunkfilename)).

In case you don't need to split the code, you import them regularly and [ES modules](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#es6-recommended-) are recommended.

```
import Library1 from "Library1"
import Library2 from "Library2"
```

For more information on code splitting see [Guides - Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) and the recommended [`import()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) function.

Comment: I need the project to be compatible with `requirejs`. Is that not possible?

Comment: You can consume any module format with webpack (even mixing them). Only the import does code splitting, so you're fine by using `import` in your code. If some of the third party code imports something dynamically you'll have to serve/load the chunks if you want to bundle them with webpack.

Comment: But I am using normal requirejs code which works with requirejs. But When I run webpack the error appears, as described in question. So what causes the problem? I still do not understand.

Comment: `require([], function() {})` is for [Lazy Loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/), if you use it, you will need to load the created chunks (bundles). Webpack understands the `define([], function() {})` and you can consume it like any other module, you don't need to use the `require([], function() {})` (which would perform code splitting).

Comment: Ok, so what do I call to import code so that both requirejs and webpack works?