# Invalid webpack configuration object

Tags: node.js, linux, webpack

I wanted to access modules like this

```
var Builder = require('Builder');
```

instead of

```
var Builder = require('./app/components/Builder');
```

So I generated a

> webpack.config.js

file using

> webpack version 1.12.13

Here is my file

```
module.exports =
{
  entry :'./app/app.jsx',
  output :{
    path : __dirname,
    filename: './client/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve :{
    root : __dirname,
    alias : {

    },
    extensions : ['.js','.jsx']
  },
  module :{
    loaders : [
      {
          loader :'babel-loader',
          query :{
            presets:['react','es2015']
          },
          test :/\.jsx?$/,
          exclude :/(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

All was fine until i updated my

> webpack to version 3.5.4

and run webpack i get this error in the `resolve object`

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
```

What is the problem and Which change do i have to make ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set base paths for my files for webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400608/set-base-paths-for-my-files-for-webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolve.root is not a valid webpack configuration property.  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

All you have to do is remove root from the resolve object

```
module.exports =
{
  entry :'./app/app.jsx',
  output :{
    path : __dirname,
    filename: './client/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve :{
    alias : {

    },
    extensions : ['.js','.jsx']
  },
  module :{
    loaders : [
      {
          loader :'babel-loader',
          query :{
            presets:['react','es2015']
          },
          test :/\.jsx?$/,
          exclude :/(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Theres several ways to resolve paths.  path.resolve is 1 way, you could use an aliases as well.  What to do would depend on what your trying to accomplish at compile time in your app.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#resolve-root-resolve-fallback-resolve-modulesdirectories

Comment: Thanks alot @thomasmeadows